# Slack integration for alarms or alerts

Tags: slack-api, reminders

I am new to Slack. I can't find any integrations for an "alarm clock"-type integration, as explained below.

What I'm looking for is a reminder to post to one of our Slack channels on a set schedule. For instance: each weekday at 9 AM, our #bug-fix channel gets a message like "do your bug fix XYZ thing."

I've searched [Slack's integrations page](https://slack.com/integrations) but can't find anything that does this. Can anyone recommend an integration like this, or point me to a resource where I might be able to find one?

Many thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: I've found an IFTTT recipe that looks promising, which I'll share here in case any one else has this same question:

https://ifttt.com/recipes/177138-post-a-daily-reminder-to-a-slack-channel

However, I don't know the Slack integrations ecosystem well. Other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe [this](http://slackhq.com/post/124767707715/googlecalendar) is a solution for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are looking for a generalizable alarm clock with static messages, or something custom. You can use [Incoming Web Hooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) to write your own custom integration. Create a simple script that you schedule as a cron job to run at 9am. If it's a weekend, your script can exit, otherwise it can grab the data it needs to post (from whatever criteria you want in your bug tracking system, or wherever) and send it to your Slack channel. 
If you search GitHub for "slack webhook" you will find examples for every language of sending a message to Slack. They make it very easy to send messages to a channel.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that Slack had web hooks!

Answer (score 5):

Just type this in Slack:

`/remind #bug-fix to do your bug fix XYZ thing. every weekday at 9am`

[Setting reminders in Slack](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/208423427-Setting-reminders)